# xslt script doesn't work when a namespace is declared in the root node

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

The xslt code below does not work for the XML file below.  However, if I remove the namespace attributes from the "objects" node in the xml file, it works as expected.  How can I fix the xslt code so that it will work when I have the namespace attributes in the root node? First posting, sorry if formatting messed up. Thanks

XML FILE:

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<object id="models" type="blah">

</object>
</objects>
```

XSLT CODE:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="object">
  <object new_attr="attr value ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </object>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT with XML source that has a default namespace set to xmlns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344158/xslt-with-xml-source-that-has-a-default-namespace-set-to-xmlns)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You needs declare and use the same xml namespace in the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sfp="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="sfp:object">
  <sfp:object new_attr="attr value ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </sfp:object>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip, that helped me narrow it down.  It has to do with the default namespace in my xml. If the default namespace is in the xml, my xslt transform does not work.  If the default namespace is removed from my xml, the xslt transform works.  So, can I make my transform work, and keep the default namespace in the xml?  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, now I see that you created a ns caled sfp like the default one from the xml, and used it explicitly in the script. Fixed it, Thanks!

Comment: @user612275: Proper etiquette at SO supposes that when your question is answered in a good way, the best way to express your gratitude is to *accept` this answer. This is done by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer. Please, do the right thing.