# Get second value from XML (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have the following XML and I only want the second value...
How can I do this?

**XML:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetVersionCollectionResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
          <GetVersionCollectionResult>
            <Versions>
              <Version AssignedTo="value" />
              <Version AssignedTo="This value I want to get" />
              <Version AssignedTo="value" />
              <Version AssignedTo="value" />
            </Versions>
          </GetVersionCollectionResult>
        </GetVersionCollectionResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

**XML Request to get each value**
(how can I change this to only get the second value?)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"></xsl:output>
        <xsl:template name="ShowVariables" match="/" >
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()='Version']">
                <xsl:value-of select="@AssignedTo" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: The language that I use is **XSLT**

Comment: Try to use this argument match="value[2]"

Comment: I changed this line "<xsl:template name="ShowVariables" match="/" >
" to "<xsl:template name="ShowVariables" match="value[2]" >" but then I do not get back any results... The result is blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [declare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344192/825783) the [namespaces](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/04/04/trxml/index.html) that are in use in your XML document in your stylesheet, too.

#### Stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:sharepoint="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="//sharepoint:Version[2]/@AssignedTo"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you want to be more precise:

```
<xsl:value-of select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/sharepoint:GetVersionCollectionResponse/sharepoint:GetVersionCollectionResult/sharepoint:Versions/sharepoint:Version[2]/@AssignedTo"/>
```

#### Output

```
This value I want to get
```

Comment: Hi Eero, many many thanks. It works! Do you know a good website/debugger to test such things?