# Transforming XML file to HTML file using XSL

Tags: html, xml, parsing, xslt

My requirement is like the following,
 1. Upload one xml file in a webpage 
 2. Parse the uploaded xml using xsl file
 3. Show the result in html table in the same webpage.

But I couldn't do the parsing with my xml file. I tried with simple xml file and it worked.
And my xml file would look like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<DCinemaSecurityMessage xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
   <AuthenticatedPublic Id="ID_AuthenticatedPublic"> 
      <MessageId>urn:uuid:3963b8fc-e989-4be2-a5d4-139d8561643c</MessageId>
      <MessageType>http://www.smpte-ra.org/430-1/2006/KDM#kdm-key-type</MessageType>
      <AnnotationText>NBS</AnnotationText>
      <IssueDate>2016-02-25T17:43:29-00:00</IssueDate>
      <Signer>
         <ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">dnQualifier=vV59D4u5w9rnFOyDPugA9tpTE7Y=,OU=.Signature.DC.CA.DVS,O=.DC.CA.DVS,CN=.ClipsterDCI.Signature </ds:X509IssuerName>
         <ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">139130018</ds:X509SerialNumber>
      </Signer>
      <RequiredExtensions>
         <KDMRequiredExtensions xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM">
            <Recipient><X509IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">dnQualifier=vUlg/0Tl/y5rXEFbSb7xF76F/2U=,CN=.DC.DOLPHIN.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">25149</ds:X509SerialNumber></X509IssuerSerial><X509SubjectName>dnQualifier=ejcAIJ/TlzuipjwSFRTGhPT/8go=,CN=LE SPB MD SM.DCP2000-200007-03.DC.DC2.SMPTE,OU=DC.DOREMILABS.COM,O=DC2.SMPTE.DOREMILABS.COM</X509SubjectName>
           </Recipient>
           <CompositionPlaylistId>urn:uuid:16e5f6c6-89b5-4c0e-a01d-79dcdf792daa</CompositionPlaylistId>
           <ContentTitleText>American_Pastoral_FTR-3-Temp_S_EN-XX_OV_20_2K_LS_20160218_NBS_IOP_OV</ContentTitleText>
           <ContentKeysNotValidBefore>2016-02-25T20:00:00-00:00</ContentKeysNotValidBefore>
           <ContentKeysNotValidAfter>2016-02-25T21:00:00-00:00</ContentKeysNotValidAfter>
           <AuthorizedDeviceInfo>
               <DeviceListIdentifier>urn:uuid:6fb7b1ef-1086-49b7-9f98-02333006fdfa</DeviceListIdentifier>
               <DeviceList><CertificateThumbprint>2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=</CertificateThumbprint></DeviceList>
          </AuthorizedDeviceInfo>
          <KeyIdList><TypedKeyId><KeyType>MDIK</KeyType><KeyId>urn:uuid:ac20730a-7172-4f5e-9f90-f9b8aac31a90</KeyId></TypedKeyId><TypedKeyId><KeyType>MDAK</KeyType><KeyId>urn:uuid:d93306ef-b0f8-43cc-adfd-ac534cdf8412</KeyId></TypedKeyId></KeyIdList>
        </KDMRequiredExtensions>
   </RequiredExtensions><NonCriticalExtensions/>
   </AuthenticatedPublic>
   </DCinemaSecurityMessage>
```

And I need to display  **IssueDate, ContentTitleText, ContentKeysNotValidBefore, ContentKeysNotValidAfter, CompositionPlaylistId** contents from this xml. And I used [http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp][1] link for parsing. But I couldn't do it with uploading xml file in the same page.

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the issue?
XSL file,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:kdm="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM" >
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
         <h2>Parsed Data</h2>
         <table border="1">
           <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Created Date</th>
             <th>Valid from</th>
             <th>Valid to</th>
             <th>UUID</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="/DCinemaSecurityMessage/AuthenticatedPublic/RequiredExtensions/KDMRequiredExtensions/ContentTitleText" /></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="/DCinemaSecurityMessage/AuthenticatedPublic/IssueDate" /></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="/DCinemaSecurityMessage/AuthenticatedPublic/RequiredExtensions/KDMRequiredExtensions/ContentKeysNotValidBefore" /></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="/DCinemaSecurityMessage/AuthenticatedPublic/RequiredExtensions/KDMRequiredExtensions/ContentKeysNotValidAfter" /></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="/DCinemaSecurityMessage/AuthenticatedPublic/RequiredExtensions/KDMRequiredExtensions/CompositionPlaylistId" /></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     </body>
    </html>
     </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And there is no error message but the table have no values from the xml

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the expected output, your XSLT stylesheet, and the error message you're getting.  Without that the question is not answerable.

Comment: And have one more problem with this. When running the html file directly in browser(in chrome) (so the url will start like file:///) the content is blank when console the output I get the following error,   **XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/saritha/workspace/parse-xml/test.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**

Comment: But its works perfectly in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a namespace issue ([like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344192/2115381)).
For a first test try to remove the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM"` form your xml.

If this works but should not be the final solution you need to add the namespace  with an prefix to your xslt `xmlns:x="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-3/2006/ETM"` and use this prefix in your xpaht.

For example:

```
<td>
  <xsl:value-of 
      select="/x:DCinemaSecurityMessage/x:AuthenticatedPublic/x:IssueDate" />
</td>
```

Update:
Please consider that **KDMRequiredExtensions** has also a default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/430-1/2006/KDM`)
Therefor use `kdm:KDMRequiredExtensions`

```
 <xsl:value-of 
            select="/x:DCinemaSecurityMessage
           /x:AuthenticatedPublic
           /x:RequiredExtensions
           /kdm:KDMRequiredExtensions
           /kdm:ContentTitleText" />
```

Update doe to additional question in comment:
**Q: but how can we identify this namespace can be used for this element?**
  Each xml node can have it own (new) default namespace `xmlns="/url/"`. This namespace is than uses for this node and any children node (but could be changed again) 
In your example ContentTitleText has no default namespace declaration therefore the one from the parent is still valid.
In your xslt you need to have a for each of this namespaces a namespace declaration with prefix and than you have to use this prefix.

Comment: Of course, this is only an example. You need to adapt all you xpath accordingly

Comment: Ok... Since I am new to this, but how can we identify this namespace can be used for this element?

Comment: Yes.. Got it. Thank you :-)

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark the answer as valid.